# router compatibility with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I have Ubuntu 12.04.

Previously I was using another router for internet access, and it was working
fine.

Now I have changed my router to d-link DSL 2750u: it connected once, and fter that I shut down my laptop.

When I again tried to access the Net through the wireless connection, the network name was not there in the list. It was in the hidden network list. I tried to connect from there but failed.

Please tell me is there some compatibility issue of Ubuntu with D-Link router?

Comment: I have been facing the same problem ever since I changed my router to 2750U. Were you able to find a solution to this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Wifi channel to 10 (in the router settings) worked for me! Apparently, North-American standards restrict operations in channels above 11 owing to interference concerns. Therefore, some OEMs do not allow you to use Wifi channels above 11. Also, I read somewhere (on askubuntu itself, but can't seem to find the link now!) that Ubuntu (11.10 onwards) does not support Wifi channels above 11.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#Interference_Concerns

Answer (score 0):

It solved my problem. But strangely 2 laptops with 12.04 behaved differently with same D-link 2750. One could see the wi-fi router other couldn't. I changed the channel to 10 in place of auto and both could see the router.